Automatic phase sequence correction in VFD Motor Controller
In a VFD drive, is it possible to implement a phase sequence verifier, so that the VFD is intelligent enough to determine if the physical connections to the Motor terminals are in the correct sequence?
How does one go about doing this?

I would think this would be simple using symmetrical components.  If you assume ABC rotation but have ACB then you’ll have a standing negative sequence voltage near rated, and very little positive sequence voltage.

@relayman357, can you explain your comment? Won't either ABC or ACB wiring look electrically identical?

Hi @Transistor, I misinterpreted what 7.62mm nato was asking.  I was thinking he meant incoming 3-phase, not outgoing to the driven motor.  Sorry about that.

I have never seen a VFD that could determine phase sequence of the motor windings while stationary.
If the motor is rotating it can determine direction to continue, for example when using flying start.
Also, some VFD can use an encoder to determine motor direction.

As far as the VFD is concerned a motor with reverse phase sequence looks electrically identical to one with correct phase sequence. There is no way to identify rotation direction from the motor terminal voltages and current.
